# Windows fan control util for Acer, porting to linux as kernel module

Tags: c, linux, hardware, kernel-module

So I have an Acer 7551g, and i'm using this utlity for windows to control the fan speed because acer sucks.

https://github.com/Gabriel-LG/Acer7551GFanControl

This works really well and keeps the laptop from overheating and shutting down. However, i'm not a fan of windows and have my laptop setup to dual boot into Arch and have all of my development stuff setup just the way I like it. I decided to try to port the windows fan control util into linux in the form of a kernel module. I have the code written, but it's not working like I thought it might.

Could someone with linux kernel chops take a look at my code below and compare it to the code referenced above and see what I am missing?? Full disclosure, I am not a C programmer, this is based on the tutorials in the linux kernel module developers guide.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/io.h>

#define EC_VAL 0x62
#define EC_CMD 0x66

static void wait_write_ec(void)
{
  while((inb(EC_CMD) & 0x02) != 0) {

  }
}

static void wait_read_ec(void)
{
  while ((inb(EC_CMD) & 0x01) == 0) {

  }
}

static void write_ec(short addr, short value)
{
  wait_write_ec();
  outb(EC_CMD,0x81);
  wait_write_ec();
  outb(EC_VAL,addr);
  wait_write_ec();
  outb(EC_VAL,value);
}


static int read_ec(short addr)
{
  wait_write_ec();
  outb(EC_CMD,0x80);
  wait_write_ec();
  outb(EC_VAL,addr);
  wait_read_ec();
  return inb(EC_VAL);
}

static void set_speed(short speed)
{
  write_ec(0x94, (255-(speed * 135) / 100));
}

static int __init hello_2_init_module(void)
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "Fan control init.\n");
  short temp = 0;
  temp = read_ec(0xA8);
  write_ec(0x93, 0x14); // this should be turning BIOS fan control off
  set_speed(100);
  printk(KERN_INFO "temp: %d", temp);
  return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_2_exit(void)
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "Fan control cleanup.\n");
}

module_init(hello_2_init_module);
module_exit(hello_2_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Jason Miesionczek");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Control fan speed for Acer 7551g Notebooks");
```

Makefile:

```
obj-m += hello-1.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: the value I get for 'temp' is 164 where i would be expecting a value between 75-95 that would correspond to what i see when i run 'sensors'. calling set_speed(100) does not have any effect on the fan.

Comment: Can you verify with a printk or something what value you actually write with write_ec

Comment: for the write_ec(0x93, 0x14); call the value i get 14 (%x) or 20 (%d) are you thinking that i might not be passing the hex value?

Comment: I don't know... just wanted to ask you if you are fine with these values. I am coaching, not giving answers... good luck, hope someone out there knows what's going on.

Comment: i actually think i've got it working now. the main problem was i inverted the parameters to outb. it should be outb(value,port). i can now control the fan speed and i'm reading in valid temperature values. thanks.

Comment: Great to hear that it worked out!